# Angular: how to use child routes for master to detail views and back?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-template

I'm currently working on a master to detail view transition with child routes and I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

I have created my own module and my components in it. The module has its own router module in which the child routes are configured. Like here:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'details',
        component: DetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

In this list view (25% of the viewport width) I would like to click on an item so that the detail view (75% of the viewport) appears right next to it:

```
<div class="list">
  <mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" routerLink='details'>
      <div class="list-entry">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</div>
```

I have placed my additional router outlet in the parent component in this way:

```
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="title">
        <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
      <filter-component></filter-component>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <my-list-component></my-list-component>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet> // Details should be loaded here
    </div>
  </div>
```

My details component looks like this (The details should close when I click on the icon):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <i class="custom-icon-class" routerLink='my-list'></i>
    <h5 class="headline">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
</div>
```

My path should look like this:

Show list view only:

> localhost:3000/my-app/my-list

Show details of the selected item (maybe with an id?):

> localhost:3000/my-app/my-list/details

And when I click on the X in the detail view it should disappear, so that I land on the following path again:

> localhost:300/my-app/my-list

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. One suggestion, in details component, instead of `routerLink='my-list'` you should do `routerLink="../"`.

Comment: I tried it but it just adds my-list at the end of my path, like: localhost:3000/my-app/my-list/details/my-list. But I need: localhost:3000/my-app/my-list/

Comment: Does `routerLink="../"` add `/my-list` to the url?

Comment: What is the url that loads the parent component?

Comment: Does routerLink="../" add /my-list to the url --> YES. The parent url is /mylist. I want to go back to that route.

Comment: Shouldn't be the case. `../` is supposed to take you up a level.

Comment: But it does not.

Comment: Would you please upload a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example?

Comment: I have a very complex setup. Would take to long :(. I have to be done tomorrow...